# Issue when dealing with two forms in Django within one view

Tags: django

I have difficulties to work with 2 forms within one view. Here is my code and issue :

Model

```
class Process(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    order = models.IntegerField(
        default=0,
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ]
    )
    status = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    process_owner = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class SubProcess(models.Model):
    process = models.ForeignKey(Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    next_sub_process = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    status = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    sub_process_owner = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

Forms

```
class createProcessForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Process
        fields = ['name', 'order',]

class createSubProcessForOneShotCreationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SubProcess
        fields = ['name',]
```

Template

```
<form action="{% url 'processmanagement:create_process_subProcess_step' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Process</p>
    {{ form_process }}
    <p>Sub Process</p>
    {{ form_subProcess }}
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The view

```
def create_process_subProcess_step(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_process = createProcessForm(request.POST)
        print('form_process : ' + str(form_process))
        form_subProcess = createSubProcessForOneShotCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form_process.is_valid() and form_subProcess.is_valid():
            process_instance = form_process.save()
            subProcess_instance = form_subProcess.save(commit=False)
            subProcess_instance.process = process_instance
            subProcess_instance.save()
            return redirect('processmanagement:displayProcessAndSubProcess')

    form_process = createProcessForm()
    form_subProcess = createSubProcessForOneShotCreationForm()
    context = {
        'form_process' : form_process,
        'form_subProcess' : form_subProcess
    }
    return render(request, 'processmanagement/create_process_subProcess_step', context)
```

When creating 2 forms within one view and saving those, it looks like the data related to the name from the second form is saved in DB in both first and second objects while the first form should populate the first object and the second form should populate the second object. e.g : in the web page, you validate : process name = A, subprocess name = B, in Db you get process name = B, subprocess name = B.
How should I handle that ?
[MariaDb results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX66m.png)

I went through different topics such as autocommit, cache issue, db issue (I have changed from SQLite to MariaDB) but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) in your form instantiations so that the field names don't conflict.

Comment: You should accept the answer to let future searchers know it solved your problem.